# NativeScript vs PlutusScript

Tags: smart-contract, cardano-serialization-lib, cbor

In cardano serialization lib what is the difference between `NativeScript` and `PlutusScript`? Is there a way to convert from one to the other? I'm trying to load a minting policy script I made as a `NativeScript`, but I couldn't find any examples of this, while I can see that, spacebudz, for example uses `PlutusScript` to load their contracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `NativeScript` is a simple multisig scripting language while `PlutusScript` is a Turing complete scripting language. You can find more details and examples of `NativeScript` [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/c6b574229f76627a058a7e559599d2fc3f40575d/doc/reference/simple-scripts.md)