# Whats the Diffrance between Plutus scripts and Cardano Native Scripts?

Tags: plutus, script, smart-contract, native

What are the key differences between Cardano native scripts and Plutus scripts, from a developer's perspective?

Comment: This has been answered before, see [here](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/5973/nativescript-vs-plutusscript)

Comment: thanks man i will do